# fopen() in C returns NULL even when file exists (is returned by readdir())

Tags: c, fopen, readdir

I am trying to open a directory, and then open a file named "YouTubeSign", directory opens fine, but for some reason fopen() on the file fails even if the file exists; any ideas?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DIR *pdir = NULL;
    struct dirent *in_file;
    FILE *signature = NULL;
    pdir = opendir(argv[1]);

      if (pdir == NULL)
       {
        printf("could not open directory %s", argv[1]);
        return -1;
      }

    while (in_file = readdir(pdir))
    {
        if (strcmp(in_file->d_name, "YouTubeSign") == 0)
        {
        signature = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");
        printf("opening youtubesign");
        break;
        }
    }

    if (signature == NULL){
        printf("could not open file ");
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the file-name you get from `readdir` does *not* include the base path provided to `opendir`.

You have to create the full path using the base path, the path separator and the file-name.

Comment: Alternatively, change the working directory to the directory in question, `chdir(argv[1])`

Comment: no, it does find the file, and it prints "opening youtubesign", the point of failure is in fopen

Comment: @YakovAbrams Yes and that's what I'm telling you. The file is found, but if you print the `d_name` structure member you will see that it only contains the file-name ***without the path***. So if the current working directory of the program is `A`, and you provide `B` as argument, then the `fopen` call will try to open the file `A/YouTubeSign` and *not* `B/YouTubeSign`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an absolute file name when you use `fopen()`, composed with the directory name and file base name, e.g.:

```
char abs_path[PATH_MAX];
// ...
snprintf(abs_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", argv[1], in_file->d_name);
signature = fopen(abs_path, "r");
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that it will work from the command line when you're testing this code.  There's nothing *technically* missing here.  You need to make sure that the process is using the correct working directory.